# How use SchedulerLock for MongoChangeStream? Are there analogues?

Tags: spring, mongodb, kotlin, changestream

I have am spring mongodb application, where I am using `MongoChangeStream` for some business logic. But if there are several instances, the business logic is duplicated as many instances. So I decided to try using `@SchedulerLock` from `net.javacrumbs.shedlock`. But it did not help, the collection `shedLock`was not created either. The application works the same as if I did not add `@SchedulerLock`.

```kotlin
@Component
class BookChangeStreamListener(
    mongoTemplate: MongoTemplate
) : MongoChangeStreamListener<BookDocument>(mongoTemplate) {

    override fun createMessageListener() =
        createMessageListener(
            object : CallbackChangeStream<BookDocument> {
                @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "1s")
                @SchedulerLock(
                    name = "BookChangeStreamListenerInsert",
                    lockAtMostFor = "5m",
                    lockAtLeastFor = "5m"
                )
                override fun insert(raw: ChangeStreamDocument<Document>, body: BookDocument?) {
                    body?.let {
                        // business logic
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

config:

```kotlin
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient
import net.javacrumbs.shedlock.core.LockProvider
import net.javacrumbs.shedlock.provider.mongo.MongoLockProvider
import net.javacrumbs.shedlock.spring.annotation.EnableSchedulerLock
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoProperties
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableSchedulerLock(defaultLockAtMostFor = "5m")
class LockConfig {
    @Bean
    fun lockProvider(mongo: MongoClient, properties: MongoProperties): LockProvider {
        return MongoLockProvider(mongo.getDatabase(properties.database))
    }
}
```

build.gradle.kts:

```kotlin
implementation("net.javacrumbs.shedlock:shedlock-provider-mongo:4.34.0")
implementation("net.javacrumbs.shedlock:shedlock-spring:4.34.0")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@SchedulerLock` cannot be used for anonymous class methods. Final solution that works for me:

```kotlin
@Component
class BoookChangeStreamListener(
    mongoTemplate: MongoTemplate,
    @Qualifier("BookCallbackChangeStream")
    val callbackChangeStream: CallbackChangeStream<BookDocument>
) : MongoChangeStreamListener<BookDocument>(mongoTemplate) {

    override fun createMessageListener() = createMessageListener(callbackChangeStream)
}
```

```kotlin
@Component("bookCallbackChangeStream")
class BookCallbackChangeStreamImpl(
    val eventPublisher: ApplicationEventPublisher,
    val mapper: BookToDomainMapper
) : CallbackChangeStream<BookDocument> {

    @SchedulerLock(
        name = "BookChangeStreamListenerInsert",
        lockAtMostFor = "10ms",
        lockAtLeastFor = "10ms"
    )
    override fun insert(raw: ChangeStreamDocument<Document>, body: BookDocument?) {
        // business logic
    }
}
```